# How to create a new database in Apache Superset from a csv flat file?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, apache-superset

I am trying to create a new database in Apache Superset from a csv flat file. There are two issues. First, when I try to edit an existing database and mark the checkbox in front of "allow to upload csv", it does not get saved because of "security reasons", according to the error message.

Second, although I could follow the instructions [here](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#superset-installation-and-initialization) to initiate a template database from some sample datasets. I have no idea how can I create a new database in Superset from a series of existing csv tables. All of my searches looking for a solution has surprisingly failed to find any clue on this task.

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a new sqlite database to be used by superset you can type in the terminal:

> sqlite3 csv_database.db

Then since superset is going to [drop support](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/9748#issuecomment-624536810) for sqlite you should set to False the following parameter in superset config.py file:

> PREVENT_UNSAFE_DB_CONNECTIONS = False

Afterwards, in superset, create a new database, and link it to the csv_database.db previously created. The SQLAlchemy URI should look something like:

> sqlite:////path/to/database/csv_database.db

I check as True the following options:  Allow Csv Upload,  Allow CREATE TABLE AS,  Allow DML.

Finally select the Upload a CSV from the Sources menu in order to create a new table in superset, or update an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to answer the first question by the following python scripts:

```
# import libraries
import mysql.connector
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

# creating connection to db_file (passing csv)
def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to a SQLite database """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()

# saving the db file
if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_connection(r"/home/smirs/git_repos/mydatabase2.db")
```

I still do not have any answer the second question: `How to insert a new database (db file) into Superset?`